# SQL: finding unmatched observations using multiple criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

As I am not very practical with SQL I am dealing with what is very likely a simple problem.

I have two tables t1 and t2 and I need to find observations in t2 that are not already in t1. The two tables contain lists of people by name, last name, email address...
The problem is that I can match some people via email address while some others with name + last name and so on...
For those in t1 that figure in t2 I need to set a value to 1 and then I need a list of the others in t2 that are unmatched.

So I've done:

```sql
    UPDATE t1, t2 SET t1.value = "1"
    WHERE (t1.Mail In t2.Mail);
```

which seems to have worked, but then when I try using name + last name it does not work:

```sql
    UPDATE t1, t2 SET t1.value = "1"
    WHERE (t1.Name AND t1.Surname In t2.Name AND t2.Surname);
```

Then for a list of unmatched observation I can find people that have no match using email and people that have no match using name + last name but I would like to find the people that have no match for name+last name of those who have no match for email address.

What I've done:

```sql
    SELECT t2.*
    FROM t2 LEFT JOIN t1 ON t2.Mail = t1.Mail
    WHERE (t1.Mail Is Null);
```

and

```sql
    SELECT t2.*
    FROM t2 
    LEFT JOIN t1 ON t2.Surname = t1.Surname AND t2.Name = t1.Name
    WHERE (t1.ID is Null);
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current `update` queries are referencing the tables using a [cross join or cartesian product](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6#bmcross), that is: for each record in the first table, the query is iterating over every record in the second table, with all matching occurring through the use of the `where` clause criteria.

This is generally considered bad practice when `left/right/inner joins` can be used, per your second set of examples using the `left join`.

As such, assuming I have correctly understood your data, I might suggest the following:

```
update t1 inner join t2 on t1.mail = t2.mail set t1.value = "1"
```

```
update t1 inner join t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.surname = t2.surname set t1.value = "1"
```

Regarding your second question:

> *...I would like to find the people that have no match for name+last name of those who have no match for email address.*

You could use something along the lines of the following:

```
select q.*
from 
    (
        select t2.* from t2 left join t1 on t2.mail = t1.mail
        where t1.mail is null
    ) q 
    left join t1 on q.name = t1.name and q.surname = t1.surname
where
    t1.name is null
```

This uses a subquery to obtain an initial set of records for which the email address does not match, and then left joins the results of this subquery with table `t1` to obtain the records for which there is no matching first & last name.